# Frustration with a simple homework program that calculates call cost based on time and minutes

Tags: c++

The program prompt basically asks for a program where you have to get two inputs from the person: the time (based one military time i.e 1800 is 6:pm) and minutes long for the call.
you then take those two inputs and using boolean if then and else statements, you apply discounts, and then get a net amount. here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{  // some user variables that need inputing based on their call
  int starttime;
  int minutes;
  const float tax = 0.04;
  const float flatrate = 0.35;
  const float mindiscount = 0.15;
  const float timediscount = 0.5;
  float callrate = float (minutes * flatrate); // the standard call rate stored in a variable.
  float gross;    // the gross cost before discount
  float net;      // the net cost

    cout << "enter start time: " << endl;
    cin >> starttime;
    if (starttime > 2499) // a check put inplace so someone doesn't enter an invalid time integer
        {cout << "You entered an invalid time. Should only be based on the 24 hour clock " << endl;
        return 1;}
    cout << "enter total minutes: " << endl;
    cin >> minutes;
    gross = callrate;
    cout << "gross cost: " << gross << setprecision(2) << endl;
    {if ((minutes < 60 ) && (starttime < 1800 && starttime > 800)) // if no discounts are made, this is the final price before tax
         net = gross;
    else if (starttime > 1800 || starttime < 800) // if the call is between 6:00 PM and 8:00 AM, it gets a 50% discount
        net = gross - (gross * timediscount);}
    if (minutes > 60 )          // if the call lasted longer than 60 minutes, it gets a 15% discount
        net = net - (net * mindiscount);
    cout << "net cost: " << float (net + (net * tax)) << setprecision(2) << endl; // the final net cost with the 4% tax added.
    return 0;
}
```

i keep getting a crazy output, such as:

```
enter start time:
1400
enter total minutes:
40
gross cost: 802795
net cost: 8.3e+005

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.740 s
Press any key to continue.
```

When even the gross cost should be a very basic small number based on minutes * 0.35(35 cent rate per minute) but shows up as 802795.
what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Try printing your intermediate results at each step, or using a debugger.

Comment: It doesn't matter when the user enters valid start times, but `if (starttime > 2499)` doesn't complain for times like 0868 or 2499. You need to split the input into hours and minutes and check them separately.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
float callrate = float (minutes * flatrate);
```

`minutes` is being used uninitialized, so you're getting whatever garbage value happened to be in there. I'm not following your program logic entirely, but you may want to move that line *after* this:

```
cin >> minutes;
```

when (presuming the input was correctly obtained from `cin`, which you don't verify) `minutes` will have a real initialized value.

You also don't use `float` in that way, would be something like:

```
float callrate = (float) minutes * flatrate;
```

but the cast is not here necessary anyway, since `flatrate` is a float to begin with, and `minutes` will be automatically promoted for the purposes of the calculation. C-style casts are also considered fairly bad form in C++, so avoid them if you can.

EDIT: The same issue is cropping up here:

```
{
    if ((minutes < 60 ) && (starttime < 1800 && starttime > 800))
        net = gross;
    else if (starttime > 1800 || starttime < 800) 
        net = gross - (gross * timediscount);
}
if ( minutes > 60 )    
    net = net - (net * mindiscount);
```

If neither the first `if` or the corresponding `else if` conditions are true, then `net` never gets assigned a value, so your second `if` statement can be using it uninitialized. This will always happen if `minutes >= 60` and `starttime` is between 800 and 1,800.

You have to be careful with initializing variables, since C++ is very unforgiving in this regard. Whenever you're getting weird or garbage values, chances are very high that this is what's going on.

Comment: it works now ,however with this correction, im still getting a crazy number for the the final 'net' worth. here is my output after that correction:                                                             enter start time:
1300
enter total minutes on the phone:
100
gross cost: $35
net cost: $-2147483648

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 9.273 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: Same issue: `net` only gets assigned a value when `minutes < 60`, which is isn't with your test input. When you later do `net = net - (net * mindiscount);`, those second two uses of `net` are again with uninitialized values, so you're getting garbage values again. See edit to my answer.